# WPF control align to bottom even when content is taller than container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a control that needs to be displayed so that it is always aligned at the bottom of its container, even when the control is taller than its container.  I've set the control's `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"`, and that works fine when the container is larger, but when the container shrinks, the top of the control aligns with the top of the container and the bottom is cut off.  I need the top cut off.

```
<Window x:Class="NestedListBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        x:Name="Root"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="185" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <system:String>Test 1</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 2</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 3</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 4</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 5</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 6</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 7</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 8</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 9</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 10</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 1</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 2</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 3</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 4</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 5</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 6</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 7</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 8</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 9</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 10</system:String>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you drag the window larger than the `ItemsControl`, it remains aligned to the bottom, but as soon as the window becomes smaller, the tops align.

Instead of the `Grid`, I've also tried `DockPanel` setting the `ItemsControl` to have `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of Canvas to achieve your expected result

note that `VerticalAlignment` is removed from ItemsControl  and `Canvas.Bottom` is set to 0 to make it stick to bottom in the Canvas.

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <ItemsControl Canvas.Bottom="0">
            <system:String>Test 1</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 2</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 3</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 4</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 5</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 6</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 7</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 8</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 9</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 10</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 1</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 2</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 3</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 4</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 5</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 6</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 7</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 8</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 9</system:String>
            <system:String>Test 10</system:String>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```